# list of string not displayed

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I use spring 3. I'm trying to display a value of an object in a jsp.

```
public class UserForm implements Serializable {

    private List<String> values;
    private String date;
    ...
}
```

Here is my controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/user.htm")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private IUserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String userStat(Model model) {

        UserForm stat = userService.populateStatistique();
        stat.setDate("today");
        model.addAttribute("statistiqueForm", stat);
        return "userStat";
    }
}
```

Here is my jsp:

```
<form:form commandName="userForm" name="userForm">
    Date: <form:input path="date"></form:input>
    <br/>
    Expediteur: 
    <form:select path="values" items="${values}" />
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="create" />
</form:form>
```

In the jsp I can see the today value for the date field, but the listbox is empty.

any idea?

thanks

Comment: Where are you populating `values` in your Controller?

Comment: I assume `userService.populateStatistique();` - populates `List<String> values;` - Debug that line and see if that line is populating your values.

Comment: exactly, by userService.populateStatistique() - when i debug i see the value

Comment: Don't have time to dig into it, but looks like there's some naming inconsistency that could cause trouble -- is the command object called "userForm", "userStat", or "statistiqueForm"?  Seems like all three names are used to refer to the same object.

Comment: statistiqueForm, userStat, statistiqueForm = userForm ... copyPaste error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correctly passing the form object to the jsp page. In that page you have a list box, which has a list of potential values and a list of selected values. The object form contains the list of selected values, but you should also setup the list with all potential values. In fact you reference ${values} in the jsp, but you don't pass it to the jsp. You should add this code to your controller:

```
model.addAttribute("values", potentialValueList);
```

I also suggest you to change the name of that list to avoid confusion, so it will be easy to understand the difference from selected values to potential values.

Comment: ok but right now the listBox is empty... in the controller, i can see UserForm.values have 2 items

Comment: Yes, it's correct that the select is empty, you have to pass the list of the potential values to the page through model.addAttribute. it's impossible to select two values from an empty list, so you have to populate that list.

Comment: i already populate this list...  UserForm stat = userService.populateStatistique();   i try to feed the data in the service layer... not a good idea?

Comment: You're populating only the other list, which contains the selected values, I think. Try this: `model.addAttribute("values", stat.getValues());`

Comment: I'm trying to show you that items=${values} refers to a list that you don't pass to the page. Instead, path=values refers to your form object. Where is the list of your potential values?

Answer (score 2):

Well, use `addAttribute("values", list)` if you want it accessible in the jsp. You are currently not setting it and so it is empty.

If that list is contained in the `statistiqueForm` object, then use `items="${statistiqueForm.values}"`.